# how to read array data without assigned to array variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a file `data.json`. It has following data

```
[
"101 200",
"102 201",
"102 202",
"103 202"
]
```

How can I read this data using javascript? Notice it is not assigned to any variable and the name of the file ended up with `.json` but the data inside doesn't look like json data.

Comment: "the data inside doesn't look like json data" — The data you pasted into the question looks like JSON to me. What makes you think it isn't JSON? Or is that not an accurate representation of what is in the file?

Comment: @Quentin it looked to me as just array but I was confused. Now you said it is json then I could safely say it is json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch the file using the [`ajax` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (making sure that your server uses the correct Content-Type HTTP header (`application/json`) for the JSON file).

When the result gets passed into the success handler, it will be presented as a JavaScript array.

Answer (score 1):

***[The working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ANGH5/)***. (note: only works with HTML5)

The code:

```
  function readSingleFile(evt) {
    //Retrieve the first (and only!) File from the FileList object
    var f = evt.target.files[0]; 

    if (f) {
      var r = new FileReader();
      r.onload = function(e) { 
          var contents = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
          console.log(contents);  
      }
      r.readAsText(f);
    } else { 
      alert("Failed to load file");
    }
  }

  $("#foo").change(readSingleFile);
```